# HTML5 Geolocation, ask for location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

Is it possible to ask for the user's permission to get their location on demand? It's usually asked when the page asks for the location, such as `navigator.geolocation`, but won't ask again until after the page has reloaded and the script asks for the location again.

Is there anyway to have it ask on demand, ex.) after the user hits deny?

Comment: You mean, once permission is denied, ask for it again...?

Comment: _After the user hits deny?_ Do you want to force the users? C'mon, accept?

Comment: While that does sound bad, it's not in my case. The page I am working on gets the current users zipcode from their location, and that's the sole purpose of the site, so hitting deny would be useless in this case. Although this could have other applications, such as requesting permission on page load, then displaying geolocation later on depending on what you needed to have happen on the page.

Comment: Why not just force a reload then?

Comment: This is meant for the iPhone, and it will be a fullscreen webapp, and when the page is added to the home screen, reloading the page breaks the code and makes the zip not display. It's odd, but it means that I can't reload the page.

Comment: I do not think there is a way to do this. You cannot force a user to click accept. If they click deny, then it's denied.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, I have a feature that specifically needs a location, if a user denies the site initially I want to ask again if they tap an "allow location" button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to either request location from another domain, or provide instructions on how to go into their browser and change their settings. Just like on iPhone how you have to go into settings if you accidentally deny a permission.

It's because the permission-asking is actually something implemented on a per-browser basis. You can imagine if geolocation was around in IE6 days, IE6 would automatically always accept. Your solution would have to execute based on the browser someone is using.