# HTML5 Geolocation ask again after refusal/denial

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

If a user denies the HTML5 Geolocation request for their location, is there a way to ask them again/trigger the permission request again?

I thought it might have simply been a case of clearing a specific cookie, but it looks like it is a setting that you have to specifically go in and remove from your browser preferences.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009501/html5-geolocation-ask-for-location

Comment: I wonder the same thing.
Hopefully someone will answer this. Please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

You have to either request location from another domain, or provide instructions on how to go into their browser and change their settings. Just like on iPhone how you have to go into settings if you accidentally deny a permission.

It's because the permission-asking is actually something implemented on a per-browser basis. You can imagine if geolocation was around in IE6 days, IE6 would automatically always accept.  Your solution would have to execute based on the browser someone is using.